# sphinxsearch installed 0.9.9 but came out as sphinx 0.9.8

Tags: sphinxsearch

I tried installing sphinx.

I downloaded the 0.9.9 version, but after compiling and installing, it came out as 0.9.8. Anyone has any idea why's this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are picking up the correct binary? I compiled version 0.9.9 and it displays the correct version number. You may want to try to execute something like ./src/indexer --version from the source directory to make 100% sure you are picking up the right binary.